# best practice to start a never ending background service in android devices with custom OS

Tags: java, android, background-service

What is the best practice to start a service that never stops? I have to be able to send a notification at specific times. As stated [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59906497/work-manager-on-chinese-roms-like-xiaomi-and-oppo-when-under-battery-optimizati) work manager, alarm manager, jobintent service(or any other service) wont work properly on custom OS devices such as Xiaomi. Some methods like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49465610/never-ending-background-service-java-for-android) may be good for anroid O+ (considering the restrictions on background services) but does not work on custom OS devices with battery optimizations such as Xiaomi.
I even raised this [Issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/162647511) and they confirmed that this problem is real with custom OS devices! (They said they are talking to them to do something about it!)

Any way, I found an app that managed to send notification on very exact times. It works perfectly on all devices. Out of curiosity, I decompiled their app. Most of the code was unreadable, but I found a class names WakeFulBroadcasReceiver that seems like it is starting many services and instantiating many wakelocks. But I couldn't figure out how they are actually doing it.
Here is the part of code that was intact:

```
public abstract class WakefulBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
public static final String EXTRA_WAKE_LOCK_ID = "androidx.contentpager.content.wakelockid";
public static int mNextId = 1;
public static final SparseArray<PowerManager.WakeLock> sActiveWakeLocks = new SparseArray<>();

public static boolean completeWakefulIntent(Intent intent) {
    int intExtra = intent.getIntExtra(EXTRA_WAKE_LOCK_ID, 0);
    if (intExtra == 0) {
        return false;
    }
    synchronized (sActiveWakeLocks) {
        PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock = sActiveWakeLocks.get(intExtra);
        if (wakeLock != null) {
            wakeLock.release();
            sActiveWakeLocks.remove(intExtra);
            return true;
        }
        Log.w("WakefulBroadcastReceiv.", "No active wake lock id #" + intExtra);
        return true;
    }
}

public static ComponentName startWakefulService(Context context, Intent intent) {
    synchronized (sActiveWakeLocks) {
        int i2 = mNextId;
        int i3 = mNextId + 1;
        mNextId = i3;
        if (i3 <= 0) {
            mNextId = 1;
        }
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_WAKE_LOCK_ID, i2);
        ComponentName startService = context.startService(intent);
        if (startService == null) {
            return null;
        }
        PowerManager.WakeLock newWakeLock = ((PowerManager) context.getSystemService("power")).newWakeLock(1, "androidx.core:wake:" + startService.flattenToShortString());
        newWakeLock.setReferenceCounted(false);
        newWakeLock.acquire(OpenStreetMapTileProviderConstants.ONE_MINUTE);
        sActiveWakeLocks.put(i2, newWakeLock);
        return startService;
    }
}
```

}

It seems like they are having an array of Wakelocks which is very weird. Do you have any Idea what might be the work around to have a background service that always work in this cusomt OS devices?